# Endomorphism of the tangent bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

If $M$ is a smooth manifold, $J:TM\rightarrow TM$ is a fiberwise endomorphism of the tangent bundle and $X,W$ are two smooth vector fields on $M$ what we can say about $J[X,W]$?
It is $J(X\circ W-W\circ X)$ and I think that $J(X)$ is a vector field given by $J\circ X$ if I think $X$ as a section of $TM$ but when I see $X$ as a derivation of smooth functions I don't understand how $J$ works. In particular what is $J(X\circ W)$?

Thanks for all help me.

Comment: You can't say much without knowing more properties of $J$. If $X$ and $W$ are vector fields, so is $[X,W]$, so $J[X,W]$ makes sense. Just $J(X\circ W)$ doesn't make sense because $X\circ W$ is not a vector field.

Comment: Yes. The only thing that i can say is: $J(X+W)=J(X)+J(W)$. But you agree that $J$ on a vector field works by composition? right?

Comment: Yes, sure. If $X\colon M \to TM$ and $J\colon TM \to TM$, then $J\circ X\colon M \to TM$. But we just write $JX$ or $J(X)$ instead of $J\circ X$.